# Java Exception when Switching from XP to WIN2K

Tags: java, windows, dll, operating-system, java-native-interface

I have an application that uses JNI for some native functions that are in a DLL. The application runs correctly on windows XP, however when I run the program on Window 2000, I receive the following:

[image]

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Compunetix\stixDlls\CMSCI Dll.d
ll: The specified procedure could not be found
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.compunetix.vsd.stix.main.Main.main(Main.java:165)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is the java runtime working correctly? Did you try to run other java programs?

Comment: Does that DLL exist in that location in your Windows 2000 environment?  Is it the exact same DLL as being run in XP?

Comment: @Tom - Just reinstalled java. Everything seems to be ok there

Comment: @Mark - Yes, the dll exists at that location and yep, its the same exact dll as I use on XP. Its literally being copied from XP to WIN2K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it might be that the dll uses another dll that is not available in that second machine. Use [Dependency walker/](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find exactly what dll is missing.

Comment: There were two functions missing on WIN2K. Thanks. I need to reevaluate the dll situation.

Comment: @user489041, without having it running in front of me is a bit difficult, I have used it rarely but it was pretty straightforward. I would say select Kernel32.dll in the upper part and then scroll down in the lower one till you find some dll in red or something. Typical things I have seen are missing .net or missing an specific version of IE for example.